# Why can't I see object ID for my azure web app in Log Analytics instead I see Microsoft Azure App Service's object ID?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-log-analytics

I only want one web app to access my key vault so anytime I see another web app accessing my key vault I want an alert to be triggered. To do this, in key vault access policy I have defined myWebApp to only access it but anytime web app retrieves secrets from key vault the object ID doesn't match my web app's ID in log analytics. Furthermore, Microsoft Azure App Service automatically appears in my access policy whenever web app accesses my key vault.

I'm confused as to why despite my web app with system assigned Object ID, I cannot trace it in log analytics.

Comment: How did you access the keyvault via your web app?

Comment: @JoyWang I have imported certificate from key vault  into web app and binded it with hostname. Everytime I sync the new version, log analytics audits it but rather than showing my web app object ID, I see Microsoft Azure App Object ID.